# How to turn off compulsory billing information in paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal, checkout, express-checkout

On PayPal page,when user is opting for pay with credit/debit card. He must fill information such as his name,phone no. How can i turn this off, as i am selling digital goods.

Comment: last time i read there is no such flag in the new REST API. it can be done using the old api, though. check out more at https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/issues/57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems they have implemented it in the last days. check out the REST method at 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payment-experience

```
Request Sample

curl -v POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>' \
-d '{
    "name": "YeowZa! T-Shirt Shop",
    "presentation": {
        "brand_name": "YeowZa! Paypal",
        "logo_image": "http://www.yeowza.com",
        "locale_code": "US"
    },
    "input_fields": {
        "allow_note": true,
        "no_shipping": 0,  // <---------------right here --------
        "address_override": 1
    },
    "flow_config": {
        "landing_page_type": "billing",
        "bank_txn_pending_url": "http://www.yeowza.com"
    }
}'
```